# Looping over cursor not same count as cursor count on android

Tags: android, simplecursoradapter

In my app I´m using a SimpleCursorAdapter to display contacts.

Each view has it´s own checkbox. in order to check all, I´m going through the cursor, putting each ID to a Set, which is progressed by the getView() method to trigger checkboxes.

The problem is here:

```
   int counter = 0;
   if (cursor.moveToFirst())
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                contact_ids_to_skip.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID)));
                counter++;

            }
```

The first list entry is always triggered, because counter is 157, and cursor.getCount() is 158.

I do not know what is happening here. I thought cursor.moveToFirst() is putting the cursor into its right position, but thats not the case.

How can I solve this?

Edit: I read the contact id from the first view which wont get unchecked at any point, and it is not getting added to the set in the upper code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at your logic. First, you move to the first record. Immediately after that, you `moveToNext()`. The first item *is* being skipped.

A few options:

Move the `moveToNext()` call to the end of the loop:

```
   int counter = 0;
   if (cursor.moveToFirst())
            do {
                contact_ids_to_skip.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID)));
                counter++;
            } while(cursor.moveToNext())
```

Change `moveToFirst()` to `moveToPosition(-1)`:

```
   int counter = 0;
   if (cursor.moveToPosition(-1))
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                contact_ids_to_skip.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID)));
                counter++;
            }
```

Or, simply get rid of `moveToFirst()` altogether:

```
   int counter = 0;
   while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
       contact_ids_to_skip.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID)));
       counter++;
   }
```

The last works because when a `Cursor` is returned from any query method, it's position is -1, which is "before the first item". So, a `moveToNext()` puts it in the right spot. Only use that one if the Cursor has just been returned from a query, though. If its position has been changed, use one of the first two methods.

Comment: Thank you =) the do-while loop did the job, now it works fine